# QDateTime not accepted by QTableView

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5, qt4

I am designing a major user interface with several fields and functions. 
However in order to shrink the problem I created a small application with 4 columns: name, image, dataDatabase, dateTime.

I have a MainWindow with a QTableView, as soon as I right click inside the QTableView an AddItemDialog opens up with:

1. nameLineEdit
2. ImLineEdit
3. imageLineEdit
4. dateTimeEdit

The issue that I have is that I can't find a way to accept the 4) dateTimeEdit through the AddItemDialog.

I didn't "go to slot" of the dateTimeEdit as I didn't think that I had to.
I think that I am not doing the proper conversion for the date and time but please advise on what the issue might be.

I am including the most important parts of the application below with the related description of the procedure I followed:

I created an Item with the fields **item.h**:

```
class Item
{
public:
    Item(const double dateTime,
         const QString &name = "", const QString &image = "",
         const QByteArray &imagesData = QByteArray());
    QString name() const { return mName; }
    QString image() const { return mImage; }
    QByteArray imagesData() const { return mImagesData; }
    double dateTime() const { return mDateTime; }
private:
    QString mName;
    QString mImage;
    QByteArray mImagesData;
    double mDateTime;
};
```

and its related **item.cpp**

```
Item::Item(const double dateTime,
           const QString &name, const QString &image,
           const QByteArray &imagesData)
{
    mName = name;
    mImage = image;
    mImagesData = imagesData;
    mDateTime = dateTime;
}
```

I created a **database.h** table that will contain the parameters as follows:

```
class dataBase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit dataBase(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool inizializationDataBase(const QString &nameDataBase);
    bool configureDataBase();
    QString getError() const { return mError; }
    bool addItem(const Item &item);
private:
    QSqlDatabase mDatabase;
    QString mError;
};
```

And its related **database.cpp** file - I am only including the most important piece of the code for this file:

```
#define CREATE_TABLE \
     " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Fish_Table" \
     " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" \
     ", name TEXT NOT NULL" \
     ", image TEXT NOT NULL" \
     ", dataDataBase BLOB NOT NULL" \
     ", dateTime DOUBLE NOT NULL)"

dataBase::dataBase(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
}

bool dataBase::inizializationDataBase(const QString &nameDataBase) {
    // code
}

bool dataBase::addItem(const Item &item) {
    QSqlQuery q;
    q.prepare("INSERT INTO Fish_Table (name, image, dataDatabase, dateTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    q.addBindValue(item.name());
    q.addBindValue(item.image());
    q.addBindValue(item.imagesData());
    q.addBindValue(item.dateTime());
    bool ok = q.exec();
    if (!ok) {
        mError = q.lastError().text();
    }
    return ok;
}
```

and finally the **AddItemDialog.h** and **AddItemDialog.cpp** that contains the fields I am trying to pass to the QTableView of the MainWindow.

**AddItemDialog.h**

```
namespace Ui
{
class AddItemDialog;
}

class AddItemDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit AddItemDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~AddItemDialog();
    Item item() const { return mItem; }
private slots:
    void on_toolButton_clicked();
    void on_buttonBox_accepted();
    void on_buttonBox_rejected();
private:
    Ui::AddItemDialog *ui;
    Item mItem;
};
```

**AddItemDialog.cpp**

```
AddItemDialog::AddItemDialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::AddItemDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    auto fileSystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    fileSystemModel->setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());
    ui->imageLineEdit->setCompleter(new QCompleter(fileSystemModel,this));
    QDateTime dateTime;
    dateTime.setDate(QDate::currentDate());
}

AddItemDialog::~AddItemDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void AddItemDialog::on_toolButton_clicked()
{
    auto nameDataBase = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open Images", QDir::rootPath(),
                      "Images (*.png *.jpg *jpeg *.tif *.tiff);;Any type (*.*)");
    ui->imageLineEdit->setText(nameDataBase);
}

void AddItemDialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    QFile dataBase(ui->imageLineEdit->text());
    if (!dataBase.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", dataBase.errorString());
        return;
    }
    mItem = Item(ui->nameLineEdit->text(),
                 ui->ImLineEdit->text(),dataBase.readAll());
    dataBase.close();
    accept();
}
```

So to recap:

1. I am not sure I provided the right format to the QDateTime conversion on the **Item.h / Item.cpp** and **database.h / database.cpp**
2. I am not sure how to pass the QDateTime from the **AddItemDialog.cpp** to the MainWindow

Additionally on the **AddItemDialog.cpp** I am having the following error right on the beginning:
**Constructor for AddItemDialog must explicitly initialize the member mItem which does not have a default constructor**

Thanks for providing information on this issue that I have been having for a couple of days.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: hi eyllanesc, I am using QSQLITE

Comment: you could share your .ui or better your project through github

Comment: is it ok if I pass you my Bitbucket?

Comment: pass me the link of your project

Comment: `git clone https://ERaggi@bitbucket.org/ERaggi/marine_database.git`

Comment: your repository is private and consequently I can not clone it, make it public

Comment: Sorry just changed the permission. Alternatively I created the same repository on github too if you prefer: `https://github.com/emanueleraggi/Marine_Database_Minimal_Application.git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DATETIME as a field and use QDateTime directly:

```
#define CREATE_TABLE \
     " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Fish_Table" \
     " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL" \
     ", name TEXT NOT NULL" \
     ", image TEXT NOT NULL" \
     ", dataDataBase BLOB NOT NULL" \
     ", dateTime DATETIME NOT NULL)" /// <---
```

Then change item:

**item.h**

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QString>

class Item
{
public:
    Item(const QDateTime & dateTime=QDateTime::currentDateTime(),
         const QString &name = "", const QString &image = "",
         const QByteArray &imagesData = QByteArray());
    QString name() const { return mName; }
    QString image() const { return mImage; }
    QByteArray imagesData() const { return mImagesData; }
    QDateTime dateTime() const { return mDateTime; }
private:
    QString mName;
    QString mImage;
    QByteArray mImagesData;
    QDateTime mDateTime;
};

#endif // ITEM_H
```

**item.cpp**

```
#include "item.h"

Item::Item(const QDateTime &dateTime,
           const QString &name, const QString &image,
           const QByteArray &imagesData):
    mName(name),
    mImage(image),
    mImagesData(imagesData),
    mDateTime(dateTime)
{
}
```

And then you pass the QDateTime directly as indicated:

```
void AddItemDialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    QFile dataBase(ui->imageLineEdit->text());
    if (!dataBase.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", dataBase.errorString());
        return;
    }
    mItem = Item(ui->dateTimeEdit->dateTime(),
                 ui->nameLineEdit->text(),
                 ui->ImLineEdit->text(),
                 dataBase.readAll());
    dataBase.close();
    accept();
}
```